# TIMBER. Display posts by click the category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, posts, timber

I display a posts using this code. Now i want to dispaly posts by clicking the category name below the grid. How can i do it?

```
  <section class="page-section page-section--padding-2rem">
  <div class="row grid-posts">
    {% for post in posts %}
    
      {% include 'partial/single-cards/recipes.twig' with {'post': post} %}
   
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .php template file, add the categories to the view:

```
$context['categories'] = Timber::get_terms('category');
```

In the .twig template, render the category dropdown input.

```
{% if categories %}
    <form action="{{ site.url }}" method="get">
        <select name="cat" id="cat" onchange="return this.form.submit()">
            {% for cat in categories %}
                <option value="{{ cat.id }}">
                    {{ cat.name }}
                </option>
            {% endfor %}
            <option value="0">Show All</option>
        </select>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```